# Has anybody studied the problem of finding maximal weighted rooted spanning DAGs?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, optimization

Let G=(V,E) be a directed weighted graph (not necessarily a tournament) and s be a special node of G so that all nodes in G are reachable from s. The problem is to find a subgraph G'=(V,E') of G so that
(1) G' is a DAG, 
(2) all nodes are reachable from s in G', and 
(3) the sum of the weigh of the arcs in E' is maximal.

Has anyone seen/studied this problem?

Comment: Are the weights positive?

Comment: Just make a greedy algorithm...taking the maximum weighing remaining edge and add it to the solution if that doesn't violate condition(1).